# Include transient field in script in hyperledger fabric

Tags: bash, curl, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am trying to write a bash script to invoke chaincode in hyperledger fabric, without using a cli. I am wondering how can one include transient field in the script? 
What I want to put in the transient field is the encryption key. If I specify the transient field in cli container, it would be like

*--transient "{\"ENCKEY\":\"$ENCKEY\"}"*

Thank you very much